# What is the logic behind this method of random number generation?

Tags: javascript

I was looking at some code golf and came across this way to generate a random number in JavaScript:

```
console.log(new Date % 100);
```

this generates a random number 0-100, however I can't make sense of it... are we not just doing a modulus of the epoch time? This won't be a value 0-100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript Dates works in microseconds since [UNIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). The `%` symbol is called modulus and is well described on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arithmetic.asp).

Basically, the function returns the current milliseconds since UNIX, removing 100 from that number until is is below 100, and returning that as a random number.

For a pseudo random number it isn't all bad, but you can run into issues with how often browser "ticks", that severally limits its usefulness with smaller numbers.

This problem is especially clear if you try to combine this with [setTimeout or setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified), where the "ticks" will fall a minimum of 4 milliseconds apart, possibly making your random number predictable.

I would personally recommend simply using [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) for generating your random numbers:

```js
/**
 * Returns a random number between "max" and "min"
 *
 * @param {number} [max=1]
 * @param {number} [min=0]
 * @returns
 */
function getRandom(max, min) {
  if (max === void 0) {
    max = 1;
  }
  if (min === void 0) {
    min = 0;
  }
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
//TEST
var inputMin = document.getElementById("min");
var inputMax = document.getElementById("max");
var inputbtn = document.getElementById("calculate");
inputbtn.onclick = function() {
  console.log(getRandom(parseFloat(inputMax.value), parseFloat(inputMin.value)));
};
```

```html
Max: <input type="number" id="max" min="1" value="100" /><br/>
Min: <input type="number" id="min" min="0" value="1" /><br/>
<button id="calculate">Generate Random</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends, it takes the remainder (0-99) of the time value in milliseconds, which is semi-random (as in: not very predictable) if used only once. It will generate linear sequences with duplicates if run in a tight loop.

Demo:

```js
function show(count) {
  console.clear();
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    console.log(new Date % 100);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="show(1)">Show 1</button>
<button onclick="show(20)">Show 20</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

> are we not just doing a modulus of the epoch time? This won't be a value 0-100

Actually, it will be ;)

You are right that we are doing a modulus of the epoch time. In this case, JS is trying to be "smart" and it converts both operands to a number if possible. `new Date()` is converted to the timestamp value, the `100` is, of course, a number already.
So if we have e.x. `1540808514277 % 100` the result will be something between 0 (if the timestamp is dividable by 100) and 99 inclusive (if the rest from the division is equal to 99).

Actually, the expression `new Date() % 100` can be translated to `Date.now() % 100` which is propably more clear.

The rule here is mathematical and can be expressed in one sentence:

*`a % b` results in a number from 0 to b - 1*

Answer (score 1):

> are we not just doing a modulus of the epoch time?

No..we are doing modulo 100 onto the timestamp. Not the epoch time

Answer (score 0):

I think it will do the number of miliseconds since 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 modulus 100. So that value can be between 0-100.